# How to get only 2 key values from the list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

from this list

```
A=[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
   {'b':1,'c':2,'a':3},
   {'c':1,'a':2,'b':3}]
```

how to get

```
A=[{'a':1,'b':2},{'b':1,'c':2},{'c':1,'a':2}]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result

See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

If you are in Python 3.6+, the dict are sorted in insertion order. Therefore you can do this:

```
A = [dict(list(element.items())[:2]) for element in A]
```

Comment: This doesn't work ('list' object is not callable)

Comment: @IoaTzimas I'm guessing you need to learn not to use `list` as a variable name? :-P

Comment: worked for me thanks!

Comment: sorry my mistake, my terminal was "poissoned" from another question...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result=[]
for i in A:
    temp=[k for k in i.items()][:2]
    result.append(dict(temp))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'c': 1, 'a': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`popitem` pops the last.

```
for d in A:
    d.popitem()
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of codes will do the job:

```
A=[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
   {'b':1,'c':2,'a':3},
   {'c':1,'a':2,'b':3}]

output = [dict(list(element.items())[:2]) for element in A]
print(output)
```

Result:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 1, 'c': 2}, {'c': 1, 'a': 2}]
```